# how to insert a new column to an existing index using elastic in R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am doing some elastic search work in R. I created an index named as iris.

```
library(elasticsearchr)

library(elastic)

iris<-datasets::iris

elastic("http://localhost:9200", "iris_data", "data") %index% iris
```

Now I want to add the new column to the already existing  index. I tried it using **reinde**x but could not be successful.

```
connect()

body <- '{
  "source": {
    "index": "iris_data"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "iris_data2"
  }
}'

reindex(body = body)

invisible(docs_bulk(index = "iris_data2", type = "data",res,raw = FALSE, chunk_size = 100000))
```

Please help me in adding a new field to existing index.